# What is the best way to handle multiple user requests when lot of back end calculation is involved?

Tags: python, django, server

Hi I am quite new to web application development. I have been designing an application where a user uploads a file, some calculation is done and an output table will be shown. This process takes approximately 5-6 seconds.
I am saving my data in sessions like this:
`request.session ['data']=resultDATA.`
And loading the data whenever I need from sessions like  this:
`resultDATA = request.session['data']`
I dont need DATA once the user is signed out. So is approach correct to save user data (not involving passwords)?
My biggest problem is if n number of users upload their files at exact moment do the last user have to wait for n*6 seconds for his calculation to complete? If yes is there any solution for this?
Right now I am using django built-in web server.
Do I have to use a different server to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are quiet some questions in this question, however i think they are related enough and concise enough to deserve an answer:

> So is approach correct to save user data (not involving passwords)?

I don't see any problem with this approach, since it's volatile data and it's not sensitive.

> My biggest problem is if n number of users upload their files at exact moment do the last user have to wait for n*6 seconds for his calculation to complete?

This shouldn't be an issue as you put it. obviously if your server is handling huge ammounts of traffic it will slow down, and it will take a bit longer than your usual 5-6 seconds. However it won't be n*6, the server should be able to handle multiple requests at once.

> Do I have to use a different server to solve this problem?

No, but kind of yes... what i mean is that in development the built-in server is great. It does everything you need it to do, however when you decide to push the app into production, you'll need a proper server for it.

---

As a side note, try to see if you can improve the data collection time, because right now everything is running on your own PC, which means it will probably be faster than when you push it to production. When you "upload" a file to localhost it takes a lot less time than when you upload it to an actual server over the internet, so that's a thing to keep in mind.

Comment: thank you. Just to be clear the calculation part alone will take 4 secs. So is it still ok if two users request for the calculation part at the exact moment?